# MVC3 and JSON model binding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I'm trying to use javascript/jquery to post data to an MVC controller. The two model classes involved, "Order" and "Item" are shown below, as is the controller and the client-side javascript. The weird this is that the menuID and mealID fields bind properly; the items array has the correct number of objects (2 in this example) but none of item fields do. Instead, they remain null (or 0 in the case of the doubles).

I tried wrapping data in JSON.stringify but then it didn't work at all. Also tried adding an explicit object definition in the javascript object as recommeded by some posts, like this

```
    var order = {
        "order": {
            "menuID": $('#menuID').val(),
            "mealID": $('#mealID').val(),
            "items": items
        }
    };
```

but that didn't work either. I can't find any spelling errors in the fields. Lastly, I looked at the items array in Firebug and it looks exactly as I would expect:

```
[Object { desc="ham and cheese", cost="5.5", qty="1"}, Object { desc="soup", cost="2.25", qty="2"}]
```

Any theories on what the problem could be? Thanks.

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public string menuID { get; set; }
    public string mealID { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public double cost { get; set; }
    public double qty { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Models.OrderModel order)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onPlaceOrder() {
        var x = validate();
        if (x.isValid)
            submit(x.items);
    }

    function submit(items) {
        var order = {
            menuID: $('#menuID').val(),
            mealID: $('#mealID').val(),
            items: items
        };
        $.post("/Order/Create", order);
    }

    function validate() {
        items = [];
        var isValid = true;
        var regex_qty = new RegExp(/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/);
        $('#orderItems tbody tr').each(function () {
            var msg = "";
            var x = $(this).find('span[name=desc]');
            var desc = $(this).find('span[name=desc]').html().trim();
            var cost = $(this).find('span[name=cost]').html().trim();
            var qty = $(this).find('input[name=qty]').val().trim();

            if (regex_qty.test(qty) == false) {
                msg += "Invalid or missing quantity. ";
                isValid = false;
            }

            $(this).find('span[name=msg]').html(msg);

            items.push({ "desc": desc, "cost": cost, "qty": qty });
        });

        return {"isValid":isValid, "items":items};
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I believe your items need to be {"desc":"ham and cheese", "cost":"5.5", "qty":"1"}

Comment: How would I do that? When I try JSON.stringify(order) then nothing binds.

Comment: Hold on - you are expecting List<MenuItem> and yet your model is OrderItem - shouldn't it be List<OrderItem>

Comment: No. OrderModel contains List<MenuItem>.

Comment: Can you show us more of your JS code?

Comment: Sure. Edit includes all the JS.

Comment: @Gadzooks34 - Your OrderModel has List<MenuItem>, yet your OrderItems which contain "desc", "cost", "qty" is what your js is passing back right? Are MenuItems and OrderItems the same class? Is that a typo?

Comment: Have u tried posting model without List

Comment: Yes. Without the list it works fine. It's the population of the list that's causing the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute your $.post with the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Order/Create',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(order)
});
```

I tested this in a clean MVC3 project. However, I had to modify your `OrderModel` to include `List<OrderItem>` instead of `List<MenuItem>`

P.S. Some older browser may not have native support for `JSON.stringify`, so you might want to use something else.

Comment: I don't think `JSON.stringify` is required to POST from Jquery to MVC. Was it tried without that...?

Comment: @SridharVenkat, I believe it is required due to contentType being set to 'application/json'.

Comment: @MK_Dev, thanks for the advice. I popped in the ajax call and it worked beautifully with no other modifications. I'm still annoyed that I can't figure out why this works but the call to post() does not. This does solve my problem, though, so I'm marking it as answered. I wound up adding "async: false:" to the ajax() call to get the behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I Think that Your problem it's probably related with the culture of the application, may I point out that your model have double value, with the following values `5.5`, `2.25` try to set the web.config to culture which allow to handle this kind the values

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="" uiCulture=""/>
  </system.web>
```